# Firestore Permission Denied With No Rule Change

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have been experiencing sudden permission denied errors on Firestone document reads from a Flutter app. The app has been running for a while and had no issues beforehand. No code changes or rule changes have been made, but today all document reads are being rejected when the rules should allow the read with no problem. I have tried setting the rules to public to no luck. Here is the rules that I currently have:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /appConfig/{document=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if false;
    }

    match /users/{document=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }

    match /workspaces/{workspace} {
      allow read,create;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
    
    match /workspaces/{workspace}/{document=**} {
        allow create;
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to read a document under the users collection as well as the appConfig collection.

Comment: Same. Seems like Firestore is down?

Comment: The thing is, I have a second project for dev environment, but that one seems to be working perfectly fine.

Comment: Correction, the dev environment is down as well. It seems like the auth was just cached before the issue happened

Answer (score 0):

The same situation, including part of the projects in the web. Requests are rejected as "FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions." on the same on some devices in the same region.

(Updated) The problem was fixed.

Comment: More information here: https://status.firebase.google.com/incidents/JH8hiSsfnSZHMdZqFTaC